# How can I get spacing between paragraphs while also keeping the default indentations?

Tags: spacing, indentation, paragraphs

I'm using the report documentclass, and the paragraph formatting looks something like this with two paragraphs:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ac odio est.
Morbi vel turpis ipsum.
    Pellentesque ac ultricies mauris. Vivamus turpis dui, congue a hendrerit
vitae, accumsan  id nulla. Proin laoreet est id est tempor commodo.
```

However I would like to have:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ac odio est.
Morbi vel turpis ipsum.

    Pellentesque ac ultricies mauris. Vivamus turpis dui, congue a hendrerit
vitae, accumsan  id nulla. Proin laoreet est id est tempor commodo.
```

I have tried the `parskip` package, which added the spacing between the paragraphs I'm looking for, but it also removed all of the indentations.

Comment: Please, don't; only use the indent. You're spoiling without remedy your pages, particularly if some paragraphs are short.

Answer (score 6):

since `\parindent` is set only once in the `parskip` package, this should work:

```
\newdimen\oldparskip
\setlength{\oldparskip}{\parskip}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{\oldparskip}
```