# parskip package, keep the indents

Tags: indentation, paragraphs, parskip

That may be a stupid question but is there a way to keep the indent while using the `parskip` package? I use `parskip` to keep spacing between my paragraphs while leaving the table of contents and lists intacts but I would like to keep the indents in my text.

Code 1 :

```
\usepackage{parskip}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Sub 1}

Paragraph 1

Paragraph 2
```

Code 2

```
\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Sub 1}

Paragraph 1

Paragraph 2
```

Basically I want the aspect of the table of contents (and possible lists) from the code 1 while keeping the indent like in the code 2. The package `parskip` works great but I just don't like that it deletes the indents and I'd like to find a way to prevent it from doing that.

Thank you.

Comment: Please, show us a minimal code so we can compile and see what you want.

Comment: I've added the code.

Comment: see also [How can I get spacing between paragraphs while also keeping the default indentations?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55660/579)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Package `parskip` sets `\parindent` to zero. The following example saves the old value, loads `parskip` and restores `\parindent`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\edef\restoreparindent{\parindent=\the\parindent\relax}
\usepackage{parskip}
\restoreparindent

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Sub 1}

Paragraph 1

Paragraph 2
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to save the old value of `\parindent` in another register and then restore it, instead of using `\the`? This is a genuine question: is the output from `\the` precise enough to set a register to the original value?

Comment: @Kalrish The output of `\the` has enough decimal places to restore the old value correctly. The smallest unit in TeX is: 1 sp = 1/65536 pt ≈ 0.000015258789 pt. Compare with the smallest unit of five decimal places, the "precision" of `\the`: 0.00001 pt.

Answer (score 8):

[Since 2018-08-24](https://github.com/FrankMittelbach/fmitex-parskip/blob/main/changes.txt), `parskip` package has an `indent` option.  Quoting the documentation :

> With the package option `indent` it is possible to explicitly set the paragraph indentation. Using this option without a value keeps the document
> class indentation unchanged, if it is specified with a value then that value
> is used. If the package is loaded without this option the indentation is set
> to zero.

Usage :

```
\usepackage[indent]{parskip}
```

or

```
\usepackage[indent=1cm]{parskip}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no reason for the `parskip` package to set `\parindent` to zero, except its author's preferences.

The simplest way to have `parskip` behave in accordance with its name is to comment this "feature" in `parskip.sty` — and as suggested by musarithmia, preferably have it saved as a new `whatever.sty` file in your `texmf` tree (then use `(sudo) texhash` to have it seen by `LaTeX` and of course `\usepackage{whatever}`) :

```
% \parindent=\z@
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to start changing package code directly. For one, this site depends on the assumption that everyone is using the same code base. This is what `\renewcommand` is for. Also, the `parskip` package is so minimal that you might as well copy the code into a separate file in your home `texmf` tree, change it how you like, and call it `parsep.sty` or whatever you like.

Comment: @musarithmia Right, still commenting this line is by far the simplest solution.  Thanks for the comment, see edited answer.

Comment: No need for `texhash` if you put it in `~/texmf/tex/latex/local/` or in the same directory as the `.tex` file.