# How to stop the package \usepackage{parskip} disabling the paragraph indentation?

Tags: paragraphs, line-spacing, sections-paragraphs, parskip, parindent

I would like to automatically insert vertical space between my paragraphs. Currently I am using `\medskip` before all my paragraphs. Example:

```
% proposal.tex
% Based on http://www.latextemplates.com/template/simple-sectioned-essay
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{indentfirst}

\begin{document}

\section{Introdução}

    In typesetting advertisement copy, a way of justifying paragraphs has
    become popular in recent years that is somewhere between flushright
    and raggedrightdddd setting. Lines that would stretch beyond certain limits
    are set with their glue at natural width. This single paragraph is but an
    example of this procedure; the macros are given next.

    \medskip
    Second paragraph.

\end{document}
```

Which generates:

[image]

[After searching](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49188/how-to-insert-vertical-space-between-paragraphs) I found about including the package `\usepackage{parskip}`. However after I do so, all my paragraphs indentations are disabled.

[image]

Therefore [searching again](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240751/how-to-change-separation-space-between-paragraphs) I found I could use `\setlength{\parindent}{30pt}` to reset the paragraph indentation, however I am not sure this is a nice thing to do.

```
% proposal.tex
% Based on http://www.latextemplates.com/template/simple-sectioned-essay
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{30pt}

\begin{document}

\section{Introdução}

    In typesetting advertisement copy, a way of justifying paragraphs has
    become popular in recent years that is somewhere between flushright
    and raggedrightdddd setting. Lines that would stretch beyond certain limits
    are set with their glue at natural width. This single paragraph is but an
    example of this procedure; the macros are given next.

    Second paragraph.

\end{document}
```

Which generates:

[image]

I would like to know whether there is a best way which I can include the package `\usepackage{parskip}` and keep the default LaTeX paragraph indentation, instead of overriding the overrode value with `\setlength{\parindent}{30pt}`.

Comment: Typically you want **only one** of the two format options (`parskip` OR `indention`). Are you sure that you want both? If you really want it, then here's a related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181451. The answer is from *Heiko Oberdiek* which is a very high reputation user.

Comment: While anyone complains about my documents, I like to use both. Though, thanks @Dr.ManuelKuehner, for now I am going to use your linked question to save the default value of it.

Comment: I wasn't judging -- just wanted to make sure that it's not a random wish :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `parskip` package contains a line `\parindent=\z@` which zeroes out the `\parindent`.  Thus, one can save the current `\parindent` before loading the `parskip` package, and then reinstate that value of `\parindent`.

Incidentally, overriding the `\parindent` with your `30pt` setting is a perfectly valid form of coding, though there are some who argue from a stylistic viewpoint that at least one of `\parskip` and `\parindent` should be exactly 0pt, but you would get no argument from me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\edef\svtheparindent{\the\parindent}
\usepackage{parskip}
\parindent=\svtheparindent\relax
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

[image]