# How to restore the parskip skips between list items?

Tags: paragraphs, line-spacing, sections-paragraphs, parskip, parindent

On the question [How to stop the package \usepackage{parskip} disabling the paragraph indentation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365976/how-to-stop-the-package-usepackageparskip-disabling-the-paragraph-indentation), I learned how to restore the `\parindent` value zeroed by `parskip`:

```
\edef\restoreparindent{\parindent=\the\parindent\relax}
\usepackage{parskip}
\restoreparindent
```

Now I find out, that `parskip` is also zeroing something else I do not want to. Reading [its documentation](http://repositorios.cpai.unb.br/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/parskip/parskip-doc.pdf) it explains:

> In addition, the package adjusts the skips between list items.

How to extend the code above to also restore the list items spacing, after `parskip` zeros them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring comments there are  40 lines of code in that package, you've added two lines to disable one line in the package and now you are asking to disable another 12.  It would be much simpler not to use the package at all and just keep its `\parskip` setting which is the line

```
\parskip=0.5\baselineskip \advance\parskip by 0pt plus 2pt
```

Comment: Who are you who are so wise in the ways of science?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes impressed that I can count to 40? (I can't but emacs did it for me:-)