# Paragraphs and indention

Tags: formatting, paragraphs

Latex by default indents the first line of a new paragraph, but does not leave empty vertical space.

Currently, I am writing a text with many formulas in it. I don't think this paragraph style works well in my document, because the empty space after a formula is much more recognizable than new paragraphs and this hides the structure of the text.

I started to use `\\ \\` for adding empty lines, but this seems to be really bad form.

So I have two questions:

1. How can I globally change the way a new paragraph is indicated. In particular, how can I add empty vertical space?
2. How is this usually handled in mathematics and physics texts?

Comment: don't use `// //`. Have a look at the `parskip` packge

Comment: @muxoveji: Why not?

Comment: `//` should not be used outside of tabulars - if you want a new line, insert an empty line or `\par`. It will create many underfull box warnings.

Comment: you should almost never use `\\ ` outside of alignments and certainly never `\\ \\ ` (which latex will warn about in most cases)  as the first comment said the parskip package will give a design with vertical space rather than indentation.

Comment: @JouleV that is bad advice, usually. (Even though it is true)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle AFAIK `parskip` resets the indentation (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/181451/156344)

Comment: @JouleV yes because using indentation _and_ vertical space is really bad style but also it guards against all those "hidden" paragraphs where if you just set the parskip primitive you will get unexpected space.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Actually I usually use none of them so that may be a case I haven't faced. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @JouleV section headings, lines in a center environment, list items, etc all implemented as paragraphs internally and so are affected by a global `\parskip` setting in ways that you might not expect without looking at the implementation.